# Object Conversion Pattern

Tags: java, object, dictionary, design-patterns

I have several different classes coming from external sources (unmodifiable) that represent the same concept.  For example `Address`.  I have `com.namespace1.Address` (with fields `houseNum`, `street`, `city`), `com.namespace2.Address` (with fields `h`, `s`, `c`), `namespace3.com.CoolAddress` (with fields `house_num`, `street`, `city`).

The problem is that certain web services I use require certain Address object types so I am required to create a `com.namespace1.Address` given a `namespace3.com.CoolAddress`.  The fields are easy enough to map but I'm looking for a pattern on how to do it.

From my point of view, an instance object `AddressConverter` doesn't make sense as there is no state (only behaviour) and when classes only have behaviour it boils down to static methods in a utility class.  In the long term, anytime I need to map new objects to one another, I have one place to add/modify/remove methods.  How it's done might change, but I know where the code sits (in once place) and can change the mapping when I need to.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 8):

I think what you're looking for is a *factory class*.  The factory pattern is used when you need to be able to instantiate one of several related classes, to be determined by the factory, not the developer.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

You're right to try to keep all this business logic in one place instead of doing ClassOne.toClassTwo(), ClassOne.toClassThree(),...

The most flexible way I can think of implementing this (but not the easiest by far) would be to have the factory start with a simple class with only basic common methods in it, and add handlers to a Hashtable or other container.  That way you don't need concrete implementations of every possible combinations of features.

Of course it would be quicker to have a concrete implementation for each possible address variant, but there would be a fair amount of duplicated code, and it would be a little harder to add new address class types.

Comment: +1 for the handler table suggestion -- I use that pattern quite a bit.

But use `Map` rather than `Hashtable`. :)

Comment: Factory is a creational pattern. The question is about managing existing objects rather than creating new ones.

Comment: @icepack I think the OP does want to create new instances when mapping one object to another. I think with the sentence "several different objects coming from external sources (unmodifiable)" he means the classes of the objects are unmodifiable. I base this on the following sentence: "I am required to **create** a com.namespace1.Address given a namespace3.com.CoolAddress.". I will edit the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't modify the classes themselves, I'd suggest an implementation of the [Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) pattern for each direction.  As you said, the adapter methods themselves can be static, but you can group both directions inside a single class so that the logic is all in one place.

At the end of the day you're going to be performing the same task no matter what you call it, or where you put the code.  I'd suggest that both directions live in the same file, as they'll often both need updating when either direction changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are always converting to the same Class I would keep it simple and put all you conversion code in that Class and not worry about factories and the like, especially if you are only dealing with a couple of different classes. Why does there always have to be a complicated pattern for these things?!

```
public class A {

    ...

    public static A convertB(B b) {

    ...

    }
}
```

Comment: The question says the original objects are unmodifiable.

Comment: @BrianYarger I think he meant that the class definitions are umnodifiable. I base that on the following sentence: "I am required to **create** a com.namespace1.Address given a namespace3.com.CoolAddress".

Comment: By putting the conversion logic in the class, the code is now tightly coupled. One point of design patterns is to avoid coupling of classes that can exist independently of each other. I'd advise against the advice in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are the classes you need to output `final`? If not, you could subclass them to create proper [Adapters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). Otherwise I'd go with dj_segfault's suggestion of a Factory with a table of handlers.

Or, wait -- is it just a web service you need to talk to? If so, there should be no reason your implementations of its datatypes can't be Adapters wrapping the input datatypes, or some intermediate object of your own.