# Design pattern to save the same data to different file formats

Tags: design-patterns, factory

I have a 3D animation that I Would like to output to different file formats such as .BVH, .FBX...

What is the design pattern that is suitable for implementing this kind of functionality ?

Would the factory design pattern work ? Why and why not.

Thanks

Comment: See this thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236667/object-conversion-pattern

I think it can help you :)

Answer (score 3):

I think what is important is the design instead of the pattern name. I think what you need is a kind of adapter:

```
public interface IAnimationFormat {
    void Save(Animation animation);
}

public class Bvh : IAnimationFormat {
    public void Save(Animation animation){
        ...
    }
}

public class Fbx : IAnimationFormat {
    public void Save(Animation animation){
        ...
    }
}
```

You could also add Load methods and stuff.

Answer (score 3):

It's not either Builder or Factory. It looks like the [Strategy pattern](http://www.google.com.vn/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CF4QFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern&ei=iHK2T9rtKOSfiAeamfXuCA&usg=AFQjCNGl3o_1x2n2_FUSSLX9qu5qjlOGmA&sig2=MGtJStc2cRcHs0FGuyGq4w).

Comment: Strategy Pattern looks like the most suitable solution for this kind of problem. An example here: https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-strategy

Answer (score 2):

You should consider `Builder` & `Factory` pattern for this context.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the observer pattern. Say you have observable class A and observers Class C and D.
Click SAVE on A, raise and event to  inform B, C, ....any more observers to perform the SAVE action.

http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternObserver.aspx