# How to prune an object of some of its fields in Java?

Tags: java, oop, composition

Suppose we have an object `obj` of type `Object` such that `System.out.println(obj)` produces `{a=Some text, b=Some more text, c=Even more text}`.

Now we want to make a new object `obj2` that is just `{a=Some text}` (i.e., the fields `b` and `c` are pruned from `obj`). So we define a class `A` as follows:

```
class A {
    String a;
}
```

Then we initialize `obj2` as follows:

`A obj2 = (A) obj`.

Unfortunately, I get a run time error when doing this.

**Question:** How do we define `obj2` as outlined above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that you have three fields `f1,f2,f3` in `class A`

Create a new `class B` with field `f1`

Declare a method in `class A` like this

```
public B getTrimmedObject()
```

**Set required fields of B from A.**

e.g. *set f1 and return B Object*

`Other way : use composition over inheritance`.B will become member of A and you can simply get B from A. `In this case split fields between A and B and avoid duplication`.

f1 will be part of B and B,f2,f3 will be part of A. A Constructor will set f1 value through B and f2,f3 are set with normal initialization

**EDIT:** example code:

```
public class A{
    private B b;
    private String f2;
    private String f3;

    public A(String f1,String f2,String f3){
        b = new B(f1);
        this.f2 = f2;
        this.f3 = f3;
        System.out.println("In A->B:"+getB().getF1()+":A:f2:"+f2+":A:f3:"+f3);
    }
    public B getB(){
        return this.b;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        if (args.length < 3) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java A str1 str2 str3");
            return;
        }
        A a = new A(args[0],args[1],args[2]);

    }

}
class B{
    private String f1;
    public B(String f1){
        this.f1 = f1;
    }
    public String getF1(){
        return this.f1;
    }
}



java A apple banana camel

 In A->B:apple:A:f2:banana:A:f3:camel
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting an exception is because `obj` is only of type `Object`; you can't "magically" turn it into an `A` so it fits into `obj2`. In Java, you can only cast an Object to a type it **is already**; you can't make something that isn't an `A` an `A`. Instead, you have to manually copy the properties, i.e. set `obj2.a` to `obj.a`.

One alternative to assigning `obj2.a = obj.a` is to make both `obj` and `obj2` of type `A`, with obj also being a more specific type `B`. For example, say you were to define the `A` class as follows:

```
public class A {

    public String a = "Some text";

}
```

You could then define `B` as:

```
public class B extends A {

    public String b = "Some more text";
    public String c = "Even more text";

}
```

Finally, you can create your objects as such:

```
B obj = new B();
A obj2 = obj;

System.out.println(obj2.a); // Prints "Some text"
System.out.println(obj2.b); // Throws an error
```

Please note that in the second method, obj2 **still has** the properties `b` and `c`; they are just not accessible.

Comment: Although correct explanation, still this does not address the problem of the OP

Answer (score 0):

In java every object is an `Object`. Therefore `obj` must be an `Object`. But it doesn't mean that `obj` is only an `Object`. Definitely, if you get some readable result for `System.out.println(obj)` then `obj` is extended from another class.

It is not type `A` because `A a = (A)obj` gives an error. You can see the class name of `obj` using:

```
System.out.println(obj.getClass().getName());
```

Let's assume `obj` is from class `B`. There are some things to do to do what you want.

If you can change the definition of `B` then you can `extend` class `B` from class `A`. Then `A a = (A)obj;` will work.

```
class B extends A{
    ...
}
```

But if you print `a` you will not get your desired output.

You can change class `A`.

```
class A{
    private B b;
    public A(B b){
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{a=" + b.a + "}";
    }
}
```

Then you have to create `A a = new A(obj);`. You can't cast this. But if you print `a` you will get your desired output.

Hope this might be helpful!!