# Generic DTO converter Pattern

Tags: java, dto

I have many DTO objects. Every dto class have the methods

- `convertDTO(Entity entity)`
- `convertDTOList(List<Entity> entity)`

I want  to use a desing pattern for my *dto object converter*. Which desing pattern I can use and how?

Dozer framework is good. But I want to write a generic pattern.

Comment: Patterns exist to solve problems. What is the problem you want to solve?

Answer (score 12):

If you use Java8, I'd suggest to use DTO to domain converter pattern as suggested [here](https://rmannibucau.wordpress.com/2014/04/07/dto-to-domain-converter-with-java-8-and-cdi/)

Below an implementation example:

**GenericConverter**

```
public interface GenericConverter<I, O> extends Function<I, O> {

    default O convert(final I input) {
        O output = null;
        if (input != null) {
            output = this.apply(input);
        }
        return output;
    }

    default List<O> convert(final List<I> input) {
        List<O> output = new ArrayList<O>();
        if (input != null) {
            output = input.stream().map(this::apply).collect(toList());
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

**ConverterDTO**

```
public class AccountCreateRequestConverter implements GenericConverter<AccountCreateRequest, AccountOutput> {

    @Override
    public AccountOutput apply(AccountCreateRequest input) {
        AccountOutput output = new AccountOutput();

        output.setEmail(input.getEmail());
        output.setName(input.getName());
        output.setLastName(input.getLastName());        
        output.setPassword(input.getPassword());                                

        return output;
    }

}
```

**Consumer**

The consumer class:

```
class Consumer {

    @Inject
    AccountCreateRequestConverter accountCreateInputConverter;

    void doSomething() {

        service.registerAccount(accountCreateInputConverter.apply(input));

    }

}
```

The strength of this pattern come from the easiness to use, because you could pass either a single or a list of entities, in which there can be other nested DTO to convert using their dedicated converters inside the converter parent class.
Something like this:

**nested collection DTO converter example**

```
class ParentDTOConverter {

    @Inject
    ChildDTOConverter childDTOConverter;

    void doSomething() {

        @Override
        public ParentDTOOutput apply(ParentDTOInput input) {
            ParentDTOOutput output = new ParentDTOOutput();
            output.setChildList(childDTOConverter.convert(input.getChildList()));
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many different solutions. You can find a discussion about it here
[Object Conversion Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236667/object-conversion-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do here, but based purely on what you wrote, I'd say make an interface that is implemented by all your DTOs, possibly with generic parameters.